# Pybind11 and inconsistent types deduced for lambda

Tags: python, c++, lambda, pybind11

In cpp code that I can't modify, we have custom class and custom pointers.
This class reads an object and depending on kwargs might also write it.
I need to make pybind11 bindings for it.

Depending on the arguments passed, we get const or non-const pointer to the class.
Pybind complaints about inconsistent types for lambda return type.
It all goes well for making `init()` function that works only for const or non-const objects. Unfortunately, need to support both cases.
What would be the best way to make python binding to cpp code in this case?

**Error**

```
In lambda function:
error: inconsistent types 'std::shared_ptr<myClass>' and 'std::shared_ptr<const myClass>'
deduced for lambda return type
  return *const_p;
```

How could the code below be modified to support both cases?
Using Cpp 11 compiler.

```
// those defined elsewhere
typedef std::shared_ptr< myClass > my_ptr;
typedef std::shared_ptr< const myClass > const_my_ptr;

//init function for pybind11
.def(py::init([](py::kwargs kwargs) {
    bool object_writable = py::bool_(kwargs["rw"]);
    int cache = py::bool_(kwargs["cache"]);
    std::string path = py::str(kwargs["path"]);
    if (object_writable){
        //returns non const
        my_ptr p = myClass::read_write(path)
        return *p;
    }
    else{
        //returns const
        const_my_ptr const_p = myClass::read(path, cache)
        return *const_p;
    }
}))
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with pybind11, you try to define a lambda with two different return types, namely ```std::shared_ptr<myClass>``` and ```std::shared_ptr<const myClass>```, which is simply not allowed as a single return type has to be known at known at compile time.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there is another unrelated issue with your code: you create a pointer to ```std::shared_ptr``` and the lambda returns a copy of it, that is you are leaking memory. Even worse, since you leak a ```std::shared_ptr```, the reference count of the shared object will never be zero and it won't be deleted automatically. You can directly assign ```my_ptr p = myClass::read_write(path)``` and  ```const_my_ptr const_p = myClass::read(path, cache)```. I am not very familiar with pybind, but I hope this still helps a bit to find a working solution.

Comment: Yes, the error message is pretty clear. Question is how to make a proper binding using pybind11. The question is not how to make this code compile. Thanks for the comment, updated the question with more clarity.

Comment: Can't you simply try to copy the ```const myClass``` to a non-const object (if a copy constructor exits), i.e. ```return std::make_shared<myClass>(*const_p)``` for the else case?

Comment: Right, that's probably best thing to do.

Comment: When you explicitly define the return type using the ```->``` syntax, i.e. ```[](py::kwargs kwargs)->myClass``` then the copy constructor will automatically be called when you return ```*const_p```. Next to better readability and you don't have to apply further change your code.